# SQL remove spam row, update most recent row

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I am currently making a public reference guide in PHP using MySQL. Sometimes spammers change stuff and I'd like to revert to a previous version of a page.

All versions of pages are stored so my problem is just the query.

```
UPDATE pages new, pages old SET new.status='2',old.status='1' WHERE new.ip='<spambotip>' AND new.status='0' AND old.title=new.title AND old.status='1' AND old.last_modified IN (SELECT max(last_modified) FROM pages tr WHERE tr.title = new.title AND tr.status='0')
```

However I get the following error:

> You can't specify target table 'new' for update in FROM clause

My query is meant to find all pages with status = 1 (active) that the spambot made, set that page's status to 2 (junk), then find the page with the highest last_modified, the same title and a status of 0 (inactive) and set that one's status to 1.

I think I need to use inner loops but I am having issues imagining how it could be done. I've googled around a bit but haven't found anything I could use.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How would one connect old and new version of the same page? Do they share the same id?

Answer (score 0):

edited:

```
Dim sList as String  = ... SELECT group_concat(title) FROM pages WHERE ip='<spambotip>'

UPDATE pages  SET staus=2 where  title IN (...)

 UPDATE pages SET status=1 where id IN (SELECT id from (SELECT id,  max(last_modified) from pages where title in (...) and status=0 group by title) x )
```

Comment: That doesn't work either D:

#1054 - Unknown column 'new.title' in 'where clause'